# wordpress: filter customposttype via checkbox by meta_value

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, filter

I have created a custom post type, and one of the meta_value is of this custom post types is a selectbox with 3 different possibilites to select in the backend. In the frontend there should be a list showing all of this posttypes, what already works. But above the list, these 3 different values show up as checkboxes and by checking one of the boxes, the listview should refresh and show only the posttypes, which have this meta_value stored...

i'm a bit lost, how could i realize it?

Comment: You can make a location throught javascript to the custom archives pages

Comment: that would be a possible idea if there were any archiv pages, but the posttype is always the same...

Comment: you can make this meta value a CSS class and when you check a box you hide the others